# Yii2 Multiple layouts Issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, url, layout, yii2

In my yii2 project i am using two layouts.

- Login
- Main Layout.

**Login layout**

- It is for the login page and the sign up page.

**Main layout**

- Main Layout is a bootstrap dashboard theme. Whenever the user logs in he is redirected to the dashboard which renders the main layout.

**Issues**

- I have my rbac setup.
- Only the logged in users can access the dashboard site.
- When the user is in the login page and tries to add some irrelevant url and click enter. It redirects to a page not found.
- The page not found renders the dashboard site and gives the user access to all url's
- As the roles have been setup it throws an error.

How can I make my site do nothing when the user enters some irrelevant url. For example like gmail. I enter irrelevant url **https://mail.google.com/mail/#trashfafafagfafaff** It remains in the trash page but does nothing. I am trying to do the same with my site which I am not able to perform.

ANy help would be great. Thanks!!!

Comment: In action have you define login layout?  ` $this->layout = "login";`

Comment: Yes I have defined.. Everythin works fine..but when I manually enter some text in the address bar it redirects me to page not found to a dashboard site

Comment: Make default route in web.php   `$config = [
    'defaultRoute' => 'user/login', ]`

Comment: Added but doesn't do  anything

Comment: Assign roles  in cntroller : `'roles' => ['@'],` here if user is guest, s/he will redirected to login page as u mentioned above u'r defaut url

Comment: I have that specified.. If user is not logged in he is redirected to the login page.. the problem is when manually enter some irrelevant content next to the url it redirects to page not found in the main layout which is the issue for me..

Answer (score 0):

Since, not much details are provided related to layouts. So, few things I'm assuming from my side. Hope you will understand.

***Assumptions***

- Working in Yii2-App-Basic
- Having 2 Different Layouts for Before Login & After Login. Means, You are aware of Assets.

**Directory Structure**

```
Root-Folder
    - assets
        -- BeforeLoginAsset.php
        -- AfterLoginAsset.php
    - commands
    - components
    - config
        -- web.php
    - controllers
        -- MyController.php
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

**BeforeLoginAsset.php** & **AfterLoginAsset.php** are two layouts for your application. One which is before login & after login respectively. (Which you have already mentioned in your question as Login & Main Layout.)

Assuming you know these layouts structure. (If no, then I will provide more info in details regarding this section.)

**config/web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
  'id' => 'basic',
  'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
  'bootstrap' => ['log'],
  'components' => [
    .
    .

    'assetManager' => [
      'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
    ],
  ],
  'on beforeRequest' => function ($event) {
    Yii::$app->layout = Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '@app/views/Mylayouts/beforeLogin.php' : '@app/views/Mylayouts/afterlogin.php' ;
  },

  'timeZone'=>'',
  'params' => $myParams,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {

}

return $config;
```

Here, `'on beforeRequest'` will play a major role to decide the layouts as you are already doing it.

One common controller, namely, **MyController.php** is being created which can be extended to all controller being used in your application.

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{

  public function init() {
    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
      return $this->redirect(['/dashboard']);
    } else {
      return $this->redirect(['/login']);
    }
  }


}
```

Declare condition in **init()** function of your common controller which will run for each and every controller which extended this Common Controller.

In this case, it will not go to after login pages if user is not logged in. It will throw them to before login pages. It's up to you how you implement it. It's just a idea to share with you.

*Hope It Helps You.*

Comment: I was not aware of onbeforerequest, I was actually did them using the layouts in my  controller login method. This is helpful..

Comment: @MohanPrasad : Implement it and respond me back. Will be happy to see your code running successfully. Greetings from India. *Happy Diwali*

Comment: The error page still displays the same dashboard layout tthough I am not logged in.. I found an alternative where I have designed a different layout for all my error pages.. this resolves my issue.. Happy Diwali to you too :-)